# Where can I download MSDN documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn

How can I download an off-line installation of MSDN documentation of [Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) for [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) and [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) development, so that I don't have to download it again while installing on other computers?

Comment: The documentation should be on the VS2010 disk. You'll have option to install it during in installation, near the end. Unfortunately, if you're looking for 2008 style MSDN, you won't find it, since M$ moved to a new and improved help system.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I tried to find MSDN setup in VS2010 express,  do you know where is file?

Comment: @bunty I don't think that express has help in it. I'll see where it can be obtained.

Comment: @bunty Does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264831.aspx) help?

Comment: @AndrejaKo - do you really need to write MS as M$?

Comment: @bunty There's also [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/acb9bef9-6e37-4caa-89d6-684aecd0b3ec#408f8733-a0f9-4ded-9dab-baa14cfb9b52)

Comment: @Wil Usually not, but in **this** particular case yes.

Comment: Not an answer as I can't find definitive information, however, try downloading the VS Express ISO image as that used to have it included, (I can't see it listed anymore). It looks like, even if you have a MSDN subscription, the stand alone MSDN Library download has not been updated in some time -  http://i.imgur.com/4GPwU.png

Comment: @AndrejaKo what is so special about this case? As far as I am concerned, it just shows ignorance and stupidity.

Comment: @Wil  They stopped using MSDN library for VS 2010 and switched to a different help system. The help should be available as off-line install from the disk, but I'm not 100% sure that it's there for express version. Default settings (if I remember correctly) expect user to download help form the Internet, which could be problematic in some cases.

Comment: @Wil I believe that by switching to new help system, they made a big step back. Therefore in this particular case, I think that the $ is justified. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I'll try installing documentation using `Help Library Manager` and let you know if it works on other machines.

Comment: @Searock As far as I've seen  (but I could be wrong), you should be able to just install docs on one computer and then copy/paste them to appropriate directory on other computers. Please do let us know if it works or not.

Comment: You might look at [Package This](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/).

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20955

Comment: I'd recommend you get your hands on the [Microsoft Windows SDK ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442). It has everything you need for advanced Win32 Api development. Also, you can download an offline version of Microsoft Win32 Programmers's Reference from [phatcode.net](http://www.phatcode.net/articles.php?id=238).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&displaylang=en) may help.

For Visual Studio 2010, you can also just click on `Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Visual Studio Tools\Manage Help Settings` and then ask it to make help content available offline.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio 2012/2013 Help Downloader](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/) is a tool for downloading the base Visual Studio MSDN package for offline installation.

**Overview**

Allows you to download the current published MSDN Library books in a new format for offline installation. Already downloaded book parts skipped for downloading on reuse.